# Is there any way to run .exe on ARM64/aarch64 host machine?

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile

I have my python script code that i have converted into executable using pyinstaller for ARM64. Now i want to dockerize this executable for host machine (aarch64). AS far i know, executable is not able to run aarch64 CPU. if not then is there any other possibilities that i can depoly my python application using Docker on host machine. Also i want to hide my source code on host machine.

I have created a Docker image (aarch64 using docker - buildx) for host machine but this image has python source code (hello.py) and docker image execute this hello.py. So if someone open the terminal, one can access source file. So i want to secure this source code and other files.

Comment: You already have a platform-independent file: The .py file itself. Why do you think you need anything else?

Comment: But when i deploy this docker image on host machine (which will be delivered to customer), they can access my source file (.py) file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what's generated by pyinstalled can be decompiled pretty easily.

Comment: So what would you recommend? What is best way for deployment? I am newbie in deployment so.